Toggle effect desn't work I have to set an If instead but I don't know how
I have this effect that is an image that when clicked show another image. It is a website for a photographer and show before the image with no post production and when clicked show the photo after post production.
My question is: why when I set toggle instead of click in html the other click doesn't work like an if, so: if I click show photo "after post production", if I I click another time show me the photo again "before post production"


/** 
 * Swap image on click with fade effect
 */

function swap(t) {
  // Create a new image element
  var newImg = new Image();

  // Set the source of the new image to the data-secondImg attribute
  newImg.src = t.getAttribute('data-secondImg');

  // Add a class to the new image for the fade-in effect
  newImg.classList.add('fade-in');
  setTimeout(() => {
    newImg.classList.add('active');
  }, 100);

  // Append the new image to the parent of the clicked image
  t.parentNode.appendChild(newImg);

  // Set a timeout to remove the old image after the fade-in is complete
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Remove the old image
    t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
  }, 2000); // Adjust the duration of the fade-in effect (in milliseconds)
}
<div class="no-select imgBx col post-box" id="box_1">
  <img src="./assets/img/prima-dopo/ferrero-prima.jpg" onClick="swap(this)" data-secondImg="./assets/img/prima-dopo/ferrero-dopo.jpg">
</div>



I tried to change "onClick" in html with "onToggle" but doesn't works

There's no event named toggle.

It's not clear what you expect to toggle. When you click on the original image, it gets removed 2 seconds later, so there's nothing that you can click on again.

Instead of creating and removing images like this, put both images in the HTML. Toggle classes so only one of them is visible at a time.

I have to toggle the effect and return to old photo and again on click for the other photo. I don't know how to set the toggle or if I have to use the "if" statement

can you please use some pics that show something in your sample code?

You are already using an "active" class, so you can leverage that and do all you timing and fading with css based on the active class. This simplifies the javascript to just a few lines of code (to add and remove "active").
The html changes a little as you need two img tags, one for each image. With one starting out with the "active" class.
The css sets position for the imgBx and img elements to overlap the two images.
Try the code snippet to see the code in action.


/**
 * Swap image on click with fade effect
 */

function swap( target ) {
  for( let img of target.parentElement.querySelectorAll( "img") ) {
    img.classList.add( "active" )
  }

  target.classList.remove( "active" )
}
.imgBx {
  /* Need this so the <img> elements position relative to it */
  position: relative;
}

.imgBx img {
  /* Position both <img> elements on top of each other */
  position: absolute;

  /* Default to not visible and ignore mouse click */
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

.imgBx img.active {
  /* Change to visible and accept mouse click */
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fade-in {
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
<div class="no-select imgBx col post-box" id="box_1">
  <!-- Do not need data-secondImg, but do need two <img> elements -->
  <img class='active fade-in' src="https://picsum.photos/100" onClick="swap(this)">
  <img class='fade-in' src="https://picsum.photos/101" onClick="swap(this)">
</div>



